# Yoga 3 Pro black screen on wakeup from sleep

Tags: 14.04, suspend, lenovo

When I wakeup my computer from sleep there is a blank black screen with just the cursor. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

Answer (score 0):

Try use the old [xscreenserver](http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/install-xscreensaver-ubuntu-14-04/) that's help me also (HP Pavilion dv6000)